# Is Angular 2 ready for production use or should I use AngularJS 1?

Tags: frameworks, angularjs, web-framework

I want to learn AngularJS but on [the website](https://angularjs.org/) I see a button with the text *Try the new Angular 2*.

Is Angular 2 ready for production use or should I learn and use AngularJS 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular 2 is not yet released, it's at release candidate level though. If I were to start a new application today I would seriously consider just going with it. If you are building something large, the release will probably catch up.

AngularJs 1.5 will have more 3rd party add-ons though, more example code, howto's etc. There is some 'forward' support allowing you to make a hybrid. See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/upgrade.html

Angular 2 will be enough of a change to make a lot of knowledge about version 1 obsolete.